# Editing notification object?

Tags: android, notifications

I have created the notification object using `NotificationCompat.Builder` and then elsewhere in my service I'd like to update `value`. What is the right approach to do this? Should I cancel this object and bulid another one?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

     Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
     .setContentTitle("App")
     .setContentText("estimated value:" + String.valueOf(value))  // <---- wanna update this
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
     .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
     .build();

     startForeground(1235, noti);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to cancel your previous notification. Instead, you can simply run the identical code with different content text (in this case, changing `value`).

For more info, see the [Updating Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating) section of the Android docs.

Comment: Thanks, `NotificationManager` is exactly what I've been looking for. I've no idea why I couldn't find in my own:)